# JQuery AJAX syntax Error Bright eyes needed

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have this ajax call using jquery but in chrome throws

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

and Mozilla throws

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
200: function(){alert(200);},
```

here is my code what i am doing wrong thanks a lot.

**UPDATE it works now i was mixing success function and status sorry for the mistake**

```
function servletCaller()
{    
try 
{                
    $.ajax(
    {url:'deleteImageHelper.do',dataType: 'json',context: document.body,
    success: function(data){},
    statusCode:
    {
      200: function(){alert(200);},
      404: function(){alert(404);},
      500: function(){alert(500);}
    }
    });         
 }
 catch(Exception){alert(Exception);}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the semis after the `alert`.

Comment: There are many, many errors here.

Comment: You are missing a bracket somewhere.

Comment: He's missing a few brackets, and it's not exactly clear what he's trying to do in the `success` function. Formatting your code in a readable way would go a long way towards finding the errors.

Comment: Take a look at this syntax/formatting... it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353214/alert-jquery-ajax-status-codes

Comment: This bunch of alerts freaks me out. Have you ever heard about the console?

Comment: yeah is only a test snippet the alerts will remove when it works..

Answer (score 3):

It pays off to have cleanly formatted code. This is exactly why.

Here's your code after it's been formatted into a readable manner:

```
function servletCaller()
{    
    try 
    {                
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'deleteImageHelper.do',
            dataType: 'json',
            context: document.body,
            success: function(data)
            {
                statusCode:
                {
                    200: function(){alert(200);},
                    404: function(){alert(404);},
                    500: function(){alert(500);}
                }
            }); //This ');' is misplaced. It should be on the next line
        } //Need a ); here
    } catch(Exception) { alert(Exception); }
}
```

As you can see in my comments, you've put the `);` after the wrong `}`. Now, that the code has been formatted in a clean manner, you can easily spot the problem.

Furthermore, that block of code in your success function isn't going to execute. You probably want it to be something like this:

```
var statusCodeCallbacks = {
    200: function(){alert(200);},
    404: function(){alert(404);},
    500: function(){alert(500);}
};

//assuming statusCode is found at data.statusCode
statusCodeCallbacks[data.statusCode](); //You still need to handle the case that you get a status code that isn't in your object.
```

Since `statusCodeCallbacks` is static, you could move it outside of the `success` function too, in order to improve performance.

As another user posted, if you are using the status code of this AJAX request to execute the function from the `statusCodeCallbacks` object, then you'd want to handle that in `complete` rather than `success`. Better yet, use `.always()` on the `$.ajax()` call itself, as `success` and `complete` are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

There were loads of errors, you could try [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) next time...

```
function servletCaller() {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'deleteImageHelper.do',
            dataType: 'json',
            context: document.body,
            success: function (data) {
                var statusCode = {
                    200: function () {
                        alert(200);
                    },
                    404: function () {
                        alert(404);
                    },
                    500: function () {
                        alert(500);
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception) {
        alert(Exception);
    }
}
```

Also your `success` method is not doing a thing.

Answer (score 0):

When an Ajax call is fired to the server. You can watch the response for that call in Network tab in the firebug. Once check it out whether the server is returning Json string or not.

And when the status code is other then 200 Success function of ajax call is not called. You may declare error and completed functions also.